# How to convert individual IPs to ranges based on matching column data in CSV

Tags: bash, awk, sed, ip, port

I need to group csv data in a way such that unsorted consecutive IP addresses that have the same port data (column G) are combined into a range.

```
sort --field-separator=',' -k 7 -k 6 $filename.tmp1 > $filename.tmp2 #sort list by port then IP address
awk -F, 'BEGIN {SUBSEP=OFS=FS} ???' $filename.tmp2 > $filename.tmp3 # combine consecutive IPs into ranges
```

Input:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.34","10110 36111" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.33","1000" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.36","10110 36111" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.35","10110 36111" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.38","10110" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.39","10110 36111" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.37","10110" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.40","10110 36111" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.42","10110 36111"
```

Expected Output:

```
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.33","1000" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.34-10.184.110.36","10110 36111"
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.37-10.184.110.38","10110"
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.39-10.184.110.40","10110 36111" 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.42","10110 36111"
```

Answer (score 0):

An awk solution.

```
sort -t, -k7 -k6 in.txt |
awk -F, '
  function out(     x, ips) {
    ips = lastprefix startn
    if (startn != lastn) ips = ips "-" lastprefix lastn
    print $1,$2,$3,$4,$5,"\""ips"\"",lastportdata
  }

  BEGIN { OFS = FS; first = 1 }

  NF != 7 { ++first; next }

  {
    split($6, fields, ".")
    n = strtonum(fields[4])
    prefix = substr(fields[1],2) "." fields[2] "." fields[3] "."
  }

  NR == first {
    lastportdata = $7
    startn = lastn = n
    lastprefix = prefix
    next
  }

  {
    if ($7 != lastportdata || prefix != lastprefix || n != lastn + 1) {
      out()
      startn = n
    }
    lastportdata = $7
    lastprefix = prefix
    lastn = n
  }

  END { out() }
' |
sort -t, -k6
```

Comment: Some port lines end up being duplicated across the wrong IP addresses.

Comment: @user3665852, Can you give me a link to a data set that causes the problem, and indicate where the problem is? If you can demonstrate the error in a few lines of input you can edit your original post and it there.

Comment: I looked into this a bit more. It actually changed the IP address entirely for the same port list. It changed the IP from "169.114.181.35" to "169.89.229.35". The latter doesn't exist anywhere in the former file. I'll paste the source when I get home.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using python.  As soon as we start dealing with CSV files that are quoted I move away from sed/awk/bash.  For instance, awk won't be able to differentiate between a quoted comma and a delimiter comma.

The python solution is also doing a little IP math to allow for ranges include more than the last octet.

Here's how to execute the script:

```
$ python IPs2Ranges.py <( sort --field-separator=',' -k 6,6  input ) 
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.33","1000"
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.34-10.184.110.36","10110 36111"
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.37-10.184.110.38","10110"
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.39-10.184.110.40","10110 36111"
"A","B","C","D","E","10.184.110.42","10110 36111"
```

And here's the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import csv
import sys

def IPtoNum( IP ):
  octets = IP.split('.')
  num = 0
  for octet in octets:
    num <<= 8
    num += int(octet)
  return num

def NumToIP( num ):
  IP=""
  for x in range(4):
    IP= str(num % 256) + "." + IP
    num /= 256

  return IP[:-1]


def nextIP( IP, inc=1 ):
  num=IPtoNum(IP) + inc
  return NumToIP(num)

with open(sys.argv[1], 'r') as f:
  csvreader = csv.reader( f )
  firstIP=''
  lastIP=''
  prevIP=''
  lastPorts = ''
  for line in csvreader:
    IP=line[5]
    ports=line[6].rstrip()
    if  ports == lastPorts and IP == nextIP( prevIP ) :
      lastIP = IP
      prevIP = IP
    else:
      if len(firstIP) > 0 :      
        if firstIP == lastIP:
          print ('"%s",' * 7  % (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],firstIP,lastPorts))[:-1]
        else:
          print ('"%s",' * 7  % (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],firstIP + "-" + lastIP,lastPorts ))[:-1]

      lastPorts = ports
      firstIP = IP
      prevIP = IP 
      lastIP = IP 

  if firstIP == lastIP:
    print ('"%s",' * 7  % (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],firstIP,lastPorts))[:-1]
  else:
    print ('"%s",' * 7  % (line[0],line[1],line[2],line[3],line[4],firstIP + "-" + lastIP,lastPorts ))[:-1]
```

Comment: When using a few thousand rows and a few hundred ports this error emerges.

  File "./IPs2Ranges.py", line 36, in <module>
    if  ports == lastPorts and IP == nextIP( prevIP ) :
  File "./IPs2Ranges.py", line 24, in nextIP
    num=IPtoNum(IP) + inc
  File "./IPs2Ranges.py", line 11, in IPtoNum
    num += int(octet)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: It would be interesting to get the vaoule of IP and inc for this particular issue.  Sorry that you have to troubleshoot.  Consider putting an try: except: around the statement on line 24 to see what we're passing into that function.  This will likely identify an issue in the calling code - perhaps we are passing an invalid IP (hopefully).  It would also be helpful to display the line number being processed so you can potentially find the input line that may be invalid (assuming the issue is input and not code/logic).